# Transponer Fila/Campo

Tags: mysql, mysqldb

```
SELECT
     sum( find_in_set('Normal', Condicion) >0 ) 'Normal',
     sum( find_in_set('Baliza Erronea', Condicion) >0 ) 'Baliza Erronea',
     sum( find_in_set('Baliza Faltante' , Condicion) >0 ) 'Baliza Faltante',
     sum( find_in_set('Baliza Rota', Condicion) >0 ) 'Baliza Rota',
     sum( find_in_set('Cartel Erroneo', Condicion) >0 ) 'Cartel Erroneo'
FROM Extintores
```

Hola comunidad esta consulta lo que hace es sumarme y separarme por coma esos campos y lo veo de esta
manera[image: ASI SE VE ACTUALMENTE]

lo que yo quisiera hacer nose si es posible es transponer los datos de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta seria la consulta normal y me devuelve los valores asi:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Condicion
    FROM extintores
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta está muy amarrada a la lógica de dominio, y para hacerla un poco más general te voy a responder sacando los extintores de la discusión y llevándolo a un ejemplo típico: las pizzas.

Cada pizza es un producto único que puede haber sido confeccionado con uno o más
ingredientes

```
| id | ingredientes                 |
|----|------------------------------|
| 1  | Jamón,Aceitunas              |
| 2  | Tomate                       |
| 3  | Jamón,Queso                  |
| 4  | Queso                        |
| 5  | Tomate                       |
| 6  | Aceitunas,Tomate             |
| 7  | Jamón,Queso,Tomate           |
| 8  | Queso,Aceitunas              |
| 9  | Queso,Aceitunas,Tomate       |
| 10 | Queso,Aceitunas,Tomate,Jamón |
| 11 | Queso                        |
| 12 | Queso                        |
| 13 | Tomate,Queso                 |
| 14 | Queso                        |
```

Existe un abanico limitado de insumos que se consideran relevantes para esta lógica de dominio: **aceitunas, queso y tomate.** De manera que si sólo te importan esos tres ingredientes puedes sacar la "sábana" con una consulta como

```
SELECT
     sum( find_in_set('Aceitunas', ingredientes) >0 ) 'Aceitunas',
     sum( find_in_set('Tomate', ingredientes) >0 ) 'Tomate',
     sum( find_in_set('Queso' , ingredientes) >0 ) 'Queso'
FROM pizzas
```

Para obtener

```
| Aceitunas | Tomate | Queso |
|-----------|--------|-------|
|      5    |    7   |   10  |
```

Es una solución muy frágil, puesto que el día de mañana el gerente puede decidir modificar la política de la pizzería para incluir el jamón en los reportes, en cuyo caso habría que modificar las queries donde sea que corresponda, con consecuencias insospechadas:

```
SELECT
     sum( find_in_set('Aceitunas', ingredientes) >0 ) 'Aceitunas',
     sum( find_in_set('Tomate', ingredientes) >0 ) 'Tomate',
     sum( find_in_set('Queso' , ingredientes) >0 ) 'Queso',
     sum( find_in_set('Jamón' , ingredientes) >0 ) 'Jamón'
FROM pizzas
```

---

**Una solución más eficiente** sería, en cambio, crear una tabla de insumos donde el operador pudiese añadir registros sin cambiar el schema. Si la tabla "insumos" tuviera la forma

```
| nombre    |
|---------- |
| Aceitunas |
| Queso     |
| Tomate    |
```

Tú podrías usar una query como:

```
SELECT
insumos.nombre,
count(*) pizzzas_con_este_ingrediente
FROM
  pizzas   JOIN insumos
   ON find_in_set(lower(insumos.nombre), lower(pizzas.ingredientes))>0
group by nombre
```

y obtener

```
| nombre    | pizzzas_con_este_ingrediente |
|-----------|----------------------------- |
| Aceitunas |              5               |
| Queso     |             10               |
| Tomate    |              7               |
```

[<kbd>ver Fiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb83b9/1/0)

Si te fijas, yo como desarrollador puedo recibir una tabla de pizzas y otra de ingredientes sobre las cuales no tengo control, y es indiferente, puesto que en la query no digité el nombre de ningún ingrediente. Es más, ni siquiera conozco esos ingredientes. Mi query solamente dice:

- cuenta las filas de una tabla donde aparezca el valor de la columna "nombre" de otra tabla

Al día siguiente el gerente decide modificar la política operacional y se debe incluir el jamón en los reportes. En este escenario la query no se toca. Solamente se inserta un registro "Jamón" en la tabla de insumos, que ahora dice

```
| nombre    |
|---------- |
| Aceitunas |
| Queso     |
| Tomate    |
| Jamón     |
```

Al correr la misma query de antes el resultado ahora es

```
| nombre    | pizzzas_con_este_ingrediente |
|-----------|----------------------------- |
| Aceitunas |              5               |
| Queso     |             10               |
| Tomate    |              7               |
| Jamón     |              3               |
```

En rigor esta solución sigue siendo frágil, puesto que no eres libre de renombrar un ingrediente sin romper todo. La solución ideal sería plantear una tercera tabla que permita la relación manyToMany entre pizzas e insumos, teniendo como llave única la combinación (id_pizza,id_insumo), con lo cual si alguien quiere rebautizar las aceitunas como "olivas" daría igual, porque la relación entre IDs en la tabla intermedia permanece intacta.

Comment: muchas gracias excelente explicación!!